# phoenix upsert only writes primary keys - it does not write any optional columns

Tags: apache, hbase, upsert, apache-phoenix

```
 DataManager dm = new DataManager();
    dm.getConnection();

    String colTypesString = "(exec_id varchar not null, bucket_name varchar, state varchar CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (exec_id))";
    String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + "test" + "." + "schema_metadata" + colTypesString;
    dm.statement.executeUpdate(createTableStatement);
    String v = "UPSERT into test.schema_metadata(EXEC_ID, BUCKET_NAME, STATE)  VALUES ('123','free','active')";
    dm.statement.executeUpdate(v);
    dm.connection.commit();
```

[select * from TEST.SCHEMA_METADATA shows it did not write the optional rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJaF7.png)

Here is the phoenix dependency in my pom file:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
     <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.14.0-HBase-1.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Note:  If I execute the UPSERT from UI (Squirrel) it works correctly - all data is written.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:  Once I aligned my drivers in java and squirrel to a new driver in our hbase-phoenix server, it all worked.

The below package worked for running in jar and docker container, but it is very heavy with all of phoenix jars (I believe).  Using phoenix-client did not have all the necessary classes.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.14.0-cdh5.14.2</version>
 </dependency>
```